# ERROR ITMS-90642: "Missing Info.plist Key. Your app's info.plist must contain the 'MSMessagesExtensionStoreIconName' key."

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store

When I upload my iMessage project to iTunes Connect. I get Archive upload failed due to the issues listed below.  The 2nd issue for an app icon is pretty self explanatory however the plist issue doesn't make sense to me yet. I'm not sure how to go about fixing this. Anyone have an idea?

[image]

Here is a screenshot as proof that the app icons are set:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You haven't set any app icon for your iMessage app, that's why you are getting this error.

> This is an error indicating that you haven't set an app icon for your
>   iMessage app.  We're aware that the error message is not very helpful
>   and are going to be updating it to be more informative.  You wouldn't
>   set that key specifically, it'll be set automatically after you set an
>   app icon in the asset catalog.

Reference: [Apple Forum Post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/61229)

Comment: if my app icons are set for all the desired sizes and they are filled in, is there a way I can refresh Xcode to let it know that there are app icons available so its recorded in the plist?

Comment: @user6510422: You don't need to refresh the app, just save the asset catalog and take a new build